# Add and subtract $\overline{X}$ trick in analysis (related to sufficient statistics)

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, mean

Yet another computing question:

Why is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i} - \overline{X} +  \overline{X} - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i} - \overline{X})^2 + n ( \overline{X} - \mu )^2 $$

In other words: Why is the cross-term $$2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i} - \overline{X})(\overline{X} - \mu ) $$ equal to zero?

Please assume the common variable definitions (I don't state them explicitly, since I assume they are clear).

Comment: The definition of $\bar X$ is either *identical to* or easily shown to be equivalent to $\sum X_i = n\bar X,$ *QED.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a self-answer and I would appreciate if someone approves this:

$$2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i} - \overline{X})(\overline{X} - \mu )
= 2 \cdot ((\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}) - n\overline{X})((\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}) - n \mu) 
= 2 ((\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}) - (\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}))((\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}) - n \mu) = 0 $$

Comment: I don't think your second step is right- it looks like there is an extra $n$ floating around on the RHS, in parrticular it looks like you multiplied $\overline{X}-\mu$ by $n$. I would write $$2 \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})( \overline{X}-\mu) = 2 (\overline{X}-\mu) \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X}) = 2(\overline{X}-\mu) [ n \overline{X} - n \overline{X}]=0$$

Comment: yes, I did. But don't I have to apply the sum symbol to **all** variables, thus also to the right hand side?

Comment: No, because $\overline{X}-\mu$ is constant with respect to $i$. The $\overline{X}$ within the sum doesn't use the same index $i$ as the overall sum; it's "previously calculated". Maybe call $\overline{X}-\mu$ by $C$. We have $$2 \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})( \overline{X}-\mu) = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X}) C= 2[ (X_1 - \overline{X}) \cdot C + \cdots + (X_n - \overline{X})\cdot C]$$ The $C$ is just a multiple of each term in the sum